# How to move radio buttons, dropdown select a few pixels higher?

Tags: html, css

This seems like it would have a simple answer, but I can't seem to figure it out.
I have tried to set the padding-top to a negative value, but it doesn't do anything.
I have to do this to line up the input boxes with the text.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only add, not subtract, padding to an element.

If your moving it left or right you can use `margin-left: -1px;`
If your moving it up or down you can use:

```
position: relative;
top: -1;
```

Comment: It works for the select element, but it doesn't seem to work for radio buttons.

Comment: @egidra I just realized what I will only move it left and right. Instead try: `position: relative; top: -1;'

Answer (score 1):

You can't use margins on them, as they're inline elements. If able, just float them left, and apply the same negative margins. [Here's an example jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/A2wbz/)